# Why is it so slow to open XML files in Eclipse editor?

Tags: xml, eclipse

This happens a lot of the time, even if the XML size isn't big.

Any one have the same problem?

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391868

Answer (score 1):

Do not download a milestone build as suggested in the other answer. This has long been fixed in Eclipse 4.2.2, so simply upgrading your existing installation to 4.2.2 using the embedded upgrade manager is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in eclipse as mentioned by user1929959. If you go down in the link provided by him then you can see the solution.

You can find the fix in - http://granite.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/M20121107-1200/
corresponding update site: - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2-M-builds

**Note:**

1. But beware, upgrading your Java EE package will likely not work, the
   above update site is for Eclipse SDK only at this point, sorry.
2. If you read the complete post in the link (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391868) provided earlier then you may get more details.